# AWS Lambda /bin/sh: which: command not found - Python Subprocess

Tags: python, aws-lambda, subprocess

I get this error when running `subprocess.call('where gcc', shell=True)` in my Lambda Function.

```
/bin/sh: which: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `where`?

Comment: `where` also does not work

Comment: I've never heard of the `where` command, why do you expect it to work? I'm not sure how `where` is causing an error message that says `which`.

Comment: The best command to use is `type`.

Comment: "best" if you know your shell is bash. `command -v gcc` if you want it to work in _all_ POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: ...that said, Python has `shutil.which()`, so you shouldn't need to use `subprocess` for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, @Barmar is correct:

`type gcc` works in my lambda function where `which gcc` did not work.

Thanks!